# My Flutter can't detect the Android SDK 'Unable to locate Android SDK.'

Tags: android, flutter, android-sdk-2.3

it's my first time downloading the Flutter, and now I have this problem 'Unable to locate Android SDK.'

I tried the command 'flutter config --android-studio (my path at Android Studio in Language & Frameworks -> Android SDK) ', but now it didn't work.

Comment: Could you display the result of `flutter doctor`? Also, which code editor are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.